# Modifying an matrix surrounding elements of an element?

Tags: r, matrix

**The Question with example:**
In short I've been trying to learn how to work with matrices in R programming. I've been trying to gain access and modify elements directly surrounding a 1 with some probability of either a 0 or 1. An example would be in the bottom right hand corner of the matrix. Also I've been stumped on the edge cases.

```
//initial
1 0 0 1 0
1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

```
//after
1 1 0 1 0
1 0 0 1 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 1
```

**What have I tried?**

I have tried the for loop approach which hasn't worked at all and also can't handle the edge of the matrix because the index would be out of bound.

```
  for(row in 1:nrow(y)){
    for(col in 1:ncol(y)){
      if(y[row,col] == 2){
        y[row+1,col] = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE, size = 1)
        y[row+1,col+1] = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE, size = 1)
        y[row+1,col-1] = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE, size = 1)
        y[row-1,col] = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE, size = 1)
        y[row-1,col-1] = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE, size = 1)
        y[row-1,col+1] = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE, size = 1)
        y[row,col+1] = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE, size = 1)
        y[row,col-1] = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE, size = 1)
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking if the value is 2 and not 1 like it is in your example the `y[row,col] == 2`. This needs to be changed to `y[row,col] == 1` if you want the example in the question to work correctly.

You can also add `if` statements to check if the position you want to change is out of bounds.

```
y <- mat
for(row in 1:nrow(y)){
  for(col in 1:ncol(y)){
    if(y[row,col] == 1){
      if(row > 1){
        if(col > 1){
          y[row-1,col] <- sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE, size = 1)
          y[row,col-1] <- sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE, size = 1)
          y[row-1,col-1] <- sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE, size = 1)
        }
        if(col < ncol(y)){
          y[row-1,col+1] <- sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE, size = 1)
          y[row,col+1] <- sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE, size = 1)
        }
      }
      if(row < nrow(y)){
        if(col > 1){
          y[row+1,col] <- sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE, size = 1)
          y[row+1,col-1] <- sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE, size = 1)
        }
        if(col < ncol(y)){
          y[row+1,col+1] <- sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE, size = 1)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```